# Trouble starting up with kinect toolbox recorder

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect-sdk, kinect.toolbox

I am starting up with the kinect for the first time along with the kinect.toolbox. I was trying to use the kinect.toolbox recorder along with the color basics wpf c# provided with the microsoft developer toolkit for the kinect sdk v1.8. However, when I click on the start recording button, it doesn't create a .recorded file as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13615696/obtaining-data-from-kinect-for-specific-time). Can you please help me and tell me what I am doing wrong?

Below is my code:

```
using Kinect.Toolbox.Record;

namespace Microsoft.Samples.Kinect.ColorBasics
{
    using System;
    using System.Globalization;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Media;
    using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
    using Microsoft.Kinect;

    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Active Kinect sensor
        /// </summary>
        private KinectSensor sensor;
        Stream recordStream;
        KinectRecorder recorder;

        /// <summary>
        /// Bitmap that will hold color information
        /// </summary>
        private WriteableBitmap colorBitmap;

        /// <summary>
        /// Intermediate storage for the color data received from the camera
        /// </summary>
        private byte[] colorPixels;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the MainWindow class.
        /// </summary>
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Execute startup tasks
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">object sending the event</param>
        /// <param name="e">event arguments</param>
        private void WindowLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Look through all sensors and start the first connected one.
            // This requires that a Kinect is connected at the time of app startup.
            // To make your app robust against plug/unplug, 
            // it is recommended to use KinectSensorChooser provided in Microsoft.Kinect.Toolkit (See components in Toolkit Browser).
            foreach (var potentialSensor in KinectSensor.KinectSensors)
            {
                if (potentialSensor.Status == KinectStatus.Connected)
                {
                    this.sensor = potentialSensor;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (null != this.sensor)
            {
                // Turn on the color stream to receive color frames
                this.sensor.ColorStream.Enable(ColorImageFormat.RgbResolution640x480Fps30);

                // Allocate space to put the pixels we'll receive
                this.colorPixels = new byte[this.sensor.ColorStream.FramePixelDataLength];

                // This is the bitmap we'll display on-screen
                this.colorBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(this.sensor.ColorStream.FrameWidth, this.sensor.ColorStream.FrameHeight, 96.0, 96.0, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null);

                // Set the image we display to point to the bitmap where we'll put the image data
                this.Image.Source = this.colorBitmap;

                // Add an event handler to be called whenever there is new color frame data
                this.sensor.ColorFrameReady += this.SensorColorFrameReady;

                // Start the sensor!
                try
                {
                    this.sensor.Start();
                }
                catch (IOException)
                {
                    this.sensor = null;
                }
            }

            if (null == this.sensor)
            {
                this.statusBarText.Text = Properties.Resources.NoKinectReady;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Execute shutdown tasks
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">object sending the event</param>
        /// <param name="e">event arguments</param>
        private void WindowClosing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            if (null != this.sensor)
            {
                this.sensor.Stop();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Event handler for Kinect sensor's ColorFrameReady event
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">object sending the event</param>
        /// <param name="e">event arguments</param>
        private void SensorColorFrameReady(object sender, ColorImageFrameReadyEventArgs e)
        {
            using (ColorImageFrame colorFrame = e.OpenColorImageFrame())
            {
                if (colorFrame != null)
                {
                    // Copy the pixel data from the image to a temporary array
                    colorFrame.CopyPixelDataTo(this.colorPixels);

                    // Write the pixel data into our bitmap
                    this.colorBitmap.WritePixels(
                        new Int32Rect(0, 0, this.colorBitmap.PixelWidth, this.colorBitmap.PixelHeight),
                        this.colorPixels,
                        this.colorBitmap.PixelWidth * sizeof(int),
                        0);
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Handles the user clicking on the screenshot button
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">object sending the event</param>
        /// <param name="e">event arguments</param>
        private void ButtonScreenshotClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (null == this.sensor)
            {
                this.statusBarText.Text = Properties.Resources.ConnectDeviceFirst;
                return;
            }

            // create a png bitmap encoder which knows how to save a .png file
            BitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();

            // create frame from the writable bitmap and add to encoder
            encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(this.colorBitmap));

            string time = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("hh'-'mm'-'ss", CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat);

            string myPhotos = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures);

            string path = Path.Combine(myPhotos, "KinectSnapshot-" + time + ".png");

            // write the new file to disk
            try
            {
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    encoder.Save(fs);
                }

                this.statusBarText.Text = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0} {1}", Properties.Resources.ScreenshotWriteSuccess, path);
            }
            catch (IOException)
            {
                this.statusBarText.Text = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0} {1}", Properties.Resources.ScreenshotWriteFailed, path);
            }
        }

        private void button_Start_Recording(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string generatedName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            string recordStreamPathAndName = @"C:\" + generatedName + ".recorded";
            this.recordStream = File.Create(recordStreamPathAndName);
            this.recorder = new KinectRecorder(KinectRecordOptions.Color | KinectRecordOptions.Skeletons, recordStream);
            button1.IsEnabled = false;

        }

        private void button_Stop_Recording(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (recorder != null)
            {
                recorder.Stop();
                recorder = null;
                button1.IsEnabled = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cant see the call to `this.recorder.Record(colorFrame)` in your `private void SensorColorFrameReady(object sender, ColorImageFrameReadyEventArgs e)` method.
Try to add this.

Comment: if i remember well, the method this.recorder.Record() accepts color, skeleton and depth frame types.

Comment: yea i got it but the video recorded is a huge file, 803 mb for a few seconds. any way to deal with that issue? how can i convert it to a format that could be played online?

Comment: To bundle the array Color Frames in a known video format i suggest you to use a third part tool (i know no one).